# Single line if statement with one or more actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor

I'd like to do a single line if statement with more than 1 action.

Default is this:

```
 @if (Reservation.Status == RSVStatusType.Cancelled)
                            {
                                <div class="row no-gutters alert-danger">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                        @Resource.Reservation_Status
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                        @Reservation.Status
                                    </div>                                           
                                </div>
                            }
                           else if (Reservation.Status == RSVStatusType.Booked)
                            {
                                <div class="row no-gutters alert-info">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                        @Resource.Reservation_Status
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                        @Reservation.Status
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>
                            }
```

also i need to pass the alert-danger or alert-info css class depend on the action or condition .

i need some thing like that

```
   @(reservation.status == cancelled ? "danger" : "info")
```

any advice i tried more than way but i did bit get solution .

Comment: That should work, what happened?  Exception?

Comment: @PhilCooper error is can not implicitly convert type string to bool

Comment: `@{ var className = Reservation.Status == RSVStatusType.Cancelled ? "row no-gutters alert-danger" : "row no-gutters alert-info"; } <div class="@className">`

Comment: @StephenMuecke please example with my code

Comment: The code above in my previous comment is with your code :)

Comment: it  works thanks a lot :D but i want to give your answer is the true in my question

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer

```
 @{var className = Reservation.Status == RSVStatusType.Cancelled ? "row no-gutters alert-danger" : "row no-gutters alert-info";}
                                <div class="@className">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                        @Resource.Reservation_Status
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                        @Reservation.Status
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```